# Fluentd to read the log from both the console and log file?

Tags: fluentd

I am trying to Dockerize more than few spring application and have setup the EFK to support the applications. Currently it is getting the logs from the console however the existing applications writes the log in the file.

How do I configure the Fluentd to read the log from both the console and log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define more than 1 conf files for different locations under the parsers.d folder

like: myFirstLogLocation-source.conf and mySecondLogLocation-source.conf
and change the path accordingly.

```
<source>
  @type tail
  tag raw_nsb_log.*
  path "c:/MyFirstLogLocation/*/mylog*.txt"
  pos_file /var/log/agent/pos/mylogs.log.pos
  from_encoding UTF-8
  encoding UTF-8
```